# Update table with incremented value grouped by column

Tags: mysql

I have a self referencing table in MySQL

```
Posts
 postId
 FK_PostId
 idx
```

The idx values are currently 0 but I need to update them so that every postId has an incremented value per FK_PostId. Simply, but non-functionally written as

```
update idx = idx + 1 where FK_PostId is not null order by postId group by FK_PostID
```

Desired result

```
postId 15 FK_PostId 4 idx 0
postId 16 FK_PostId 4 idx 1
postId 17 FK_PostId 4 idx 2
postId 18 FK_PostId 4 idx 3
postId 24 FK_PostId 4 idx 4
postId 32 FK_PostId 50 idx 0
postId 35 FK_PostId 50 idx 1
```

I can't seem to get a smart query together for this.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please post the previous data so that we can see the way you get `15 / 4 / 0 ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do the trick

```
UPDATE WallPost p,

(   SELECT  @r:= IF(@u = FK_PostID, @r + 1,0) AS ROWNUM,
                postID,
                FK_PostID,
                @u:= FK_postID
        FROM    WallPost,
                (SELECT @i:= 1) AS r,
                (SELECT @u:= 0) AS u
        WHERE FK_PostID is not null
        ORDER BY FK_PostID, idx, postID
    ) AS s
set p.idx = s.ROWNUM
where p.postId = s.postId;
```

Based on a solution here: 
[query to add incremental field based on GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980957/query-to-add-incremental-field-based-on-group-by)

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> set @f := null;
mysql> UPDATE Posts 
    SET
      idx = IF(FK_postId = @f, @i := @i+1, @i := 1), 
      FK_postId = (@f := FK_postId) 
    ORDER BY FK_postId, postId;
```

Comment: you forgot to also declare `@i` variable: `SET @f := null, @i = null;`

Comment: @Dwellee, you don't need to initialize `@i` because the logic guarantees `@i` will be set initially to 1 before it is incremented. The initial state of `@f` being null guarantees that it will not be equal to FK_postId on the first iteration, therefore the "else" expression of the IF() function will set `@i`.

Comment: I don't really know how MySQL handles variables, but it seems that it returns `$i = 1` only when `FK_postId != @f`, in other cases it tries to increment undeclared `$i` and returns `null` - judging from this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b27c/1)

Comment: @Dwellee SQLFiddle is not always correct. I just tested it on MySQL 5.6.17 on Linux and it works fine. `FK_postId = @f` will always fail when @f is NULL, no matter what the value of FK_postId is, because NULL is not equal to any value, not even NULL.

Comment: I just tested it on MySQL 5.6.16 on Windows, doesn't work for me :/

Comment: @Dwellee, I can't explain that, but if you need to initialize `@i` in your environment, then that's what you have to do. It can't do any harm.